# Presto + query.max-memory-per-node configuration

Tags: java, presto

We not configured in our presto workers the parameter - `query.max-memory-per-node`

From the log seems that the value for `query.max-memory-per-node` is set automatically

```
grep -r "query.max-memory-per-node"  /presto/data/var/log/server.log
2019-08-08T14:25:03.840Z    INFO    main    Bootstrap       query.max-memory-per-node                              4402341478.40B
```

My question

Do we need to set the `query.max-memory-per-node` in `config.properties`  ?

Or value for the `query.max-memory-per-node` , will set by the presto

But as we can see from the logs , presto set only - `4402341478.40B` ( few GIGA bytes ) , so this is small size

And when query is need more memory then query could crash

Please your opinion , do we need to set the parameter  `query.max-memory-per-node`  – in `config.properties`

In order to set higher values as `20-30 GIGA`

Reference - https://prestodb.github.io/presto-admin/docs/current/installation/presto-configuration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default for `query.max-memory-per-node` is 10% of the available heap memory.  The default for this property is set here:

https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/master/presto-main/src/main/java/io/prestosql/memory/NodeMemoryConfig.java#L35

IIRC we set the default value so you could have a few large queries running in a cluster.  The exact number isn't clear from this value alone.  If you take a look at the configurations in the file linked above you will see that the system first reserves 30% of the heap for "unaccounted memory allocations", because Presto doesn't track all allocations.  Then the `query.max-memory-per-node` is only a limit on "user" memory, which is memory controllable by the query author such as `group by` and `join` hash tables.  This value does not include input and output buffers which are automatically managed by Presto.

With all of that put together, I would expect with the default values you can run 3-5 large queries concurrently on the code.

As for how you want to set these, it really depends on your workload.  If you expect to have a large mixed workload, the defaults may work for you.  If you want to be able to dedicate the entire cluster to a single worker, you can increase the values to near the heap size (make sure to leave head room for untracked allocations).

Comment: first thank you so much for the clear answer , about my cluster - yes we expect to have a large mixed workload , so from your answer I can understand that it will be useful to set query.max-memory-per-node nearly to heap size , ( example query.max-memory-per-node=50GB ) , our Xmx is 55GB ,  so please corect my if I am wrong -:)

Comment: another little thing - Do we need to set the query.max-memory-per-node in config.properties?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be set in config.properties